# URL rewrite multiple excludes

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to write a IIS Url rewrite rule that redirects all requests except two, and I can't figure it out.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

`http://server/healthcheck.aspx --> not redirected
http://server/idsrv2/2/stuff --> not redirected
http://server/stuffstuff --> redirect to http://server/idsrv2/stuffstuff`

This is the rule I have so far, but it's not kicking in:

`<rule name="Redirect everything to idsrv/2" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.*)healthcheck" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.*)idsrv2" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="idsrv2{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
</rule>`

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logical grouping in your rule should be `MatchAll`. I've changed you rule a bit and this should work in your case:

```
<rule name="Redirect everything to idsrv/2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/healthcheck" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/idsrv2" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="idsrv2/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```